# Issue with passing ID to open the modal in vue for the particular item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

The issue I am facing here is I have a modal which has "Suggested Book" based on the `prop.item.type.name`.

When I click on "Suggested Book" it opens up the modal for *all* items. I tried passing the `prop.item.id` with the `openBookDialog` but it didn't resolve the problem. Please help me solve this issue.

Template

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="books" :disable-initial-sort="true" :mustSort="true" hide-actions class="edition-table">
 <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
  <td>{{ props.item.type.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ props.item.created_at }}</td>
  <td><a v-if='props.item.file_download_url' @click="downloadFile(props.item.file_download_url)" href="#" class="details-link"><span class="hidden-xs-only">Download</span><span class="hidden-sm-and-up">Download</span></a></td>
  <td>
    <a @click="openBookDialog(props.item.id)" href='javascript:void(0);' class="details-link"><span class="hidden-xs-only">Suggested Book</span><span class="hidden-sm-and-up">Suggested Book</span>                    
    </a>                                              
    <v-dialog v-model="bookDialog" max-width="1275">
      <FilteredBookModal :document="props.item.file_type"/>
      <div class="text-xs-right">
        <v-btn class='vue-file-button text-right' @click="closeBookDialog(props.item.id)" >Close</v-btn>
        </div>
    </v-dialog>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a v-if='props.item.purchase_download_url' @click="downloadFile(props.item.purchase_download_url)" href="#" class="details-link"><span class="hidden-xs-only">Download</span><span class="hidden-sm-and-up">Download</span>
    </a>
  </td>
 </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Instance

```
<script>
  data: function() {
    return {
     bookDialog: false,
    }
  },
  openBookDialog() {
    this.bookDialog = true;
  },
  closeBookDialog() {
    this.bookDialog = false;
  },
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `bookDialog` an object that can hold the open/close state for every item, not just 1 global state:

```js
data() {
  return {
    bookDialog: {}
  }
}
```

Open and close based on the argument (nothing is being done at all with the argument in the example above):

```js
openBookDialog(id) {
  this.$set(this.bookDialog, id, true);
},
closeBookDialog(id) {
  this.$set(this.bookDialog, id, false);
}
```

Set each dialog's `v-model` based on `id` too:

```html
<v-dialog v-model="bookDialog[props.item.id]" max-width="1275">
```

Comment: I have replaced my code the way you have suggested but now the modal doesn't open.

Comment: I added console.log(id) just to check if ID is being passed and I get the ID on the console.

Comment: Thankyou Dan, It works like a champ. 
I ll study about Vue.set